# SUDS raise TypeNotFound(query.ref) suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found: '(Array, http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema, )'

Tags: python, soap, suds

I am new to SUDS and have no idea why I am getting error while trying to perform a transaction with the WSDL provider. Does it have any thing to do with the way Array is listed in WSDL file?

```
import suds, sys
import urllib
import logging
from array import *
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('suds.transport').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
url3 = "http://api.secretco.co.np/nusoap-transactions.php?wsdl"
client = suds.client.Client(url3)
countryiso2 = 'NP'
apikey = '<API-KEY>'
response = client.service.purchase(countryiso2=countryiso2, apikey=apikey)
```

I am getting the error:

```
SUDS raise TypeNotFound(query.ref) suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found: '(Array, http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema, )'
```

Following is the excerpt from the WSDL

```
...
<operation name="purchase">
<documentation>Purchase</documentation>
<input message="tns:purchaseRequest"/>
<output message="tns:purchaseResponse"/>
</operation>
...
<message name="purchaseResponse">
<part name="return" type="xsd:Array"/>
</message>
...
```

Comment: I don't think you need `from array import *`

Comment: Could be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459955/returning-an-array-of-objects-in-php-web-service